Agregar un alias en la consola de Widnows (cmd)
me gustaría agregar un alias a cmd de windows, algo parecido al alias de terminal de linux y que sea permanente, realmente desconozco el proceso en windows, ya que no suelo trabajar con este sistema.

Revisa esta pregunta https://superuser.com/questions/560519/how-to-set-an-alias-in-windows-command-line. Recuerdo que antes tenías que configurar el alias cada vez que abrías una nueva terminal, lo cual no era muy práctico. Una alternativa es crear una carpeta donde puedes guardar scripts .bat (con el nombre de tus alias) que apunten a los programas que necesitas. Luego, solo debes agregar esa carpeta al PATH en las variables de entorno, y podrás ejecutar los scripts desde cualquier terminal sin necesidad de configurarlos cada vez.

WIndows tiene symlinks (mklink).  Tal vez puede crear un symlink para el alias?  (Además, symlinks son permanantes)

Creo que Windows no soporta alias pero hay algunas alternativas.
Si el alias es a un programa, puedes crear un enlace simbólico con mklink. La sintaxis es la siguiente:
mklink alias archivo

Para que pueda ejecutarse desde cualquier parte es necesario situar el enlace en una carpeta que esté en el PATH.

Otra opción es crear un script de CMD que ejecute los comandos deseados. Es importante que su extensión sea .bat o .cmd.
Algunos detalles a tener en cuenta:

Los scripts de CMD producen eco. Puedes ocultarlo precediendo el comando de un @ o agregar @echo off al inicio del script para desactivar el eco. Por ejemplo:
@echo off
dir /b *.mp4


Si quieres que el script reciba parámetros y pasárselos al comando, puedes hacerlo con %*.
@echo off
dir /b %*


Si necesitas una lógica más complicada, puedes hacer que el script ejecute otro programa o script en otro lenguaje para que se haga cargo. Por ejemplo, con Python:
@echo off
python script.py %*




A este tipo de scripts se les llama shims y algunos programas que los usan son pyenv y nvm
